# Asynchronous rendering model in vulkan

Tags: opengl, vulkan

Recently I'm reading https://github.com/ARM-software/vulkan_best_practice_for_mobile_developers/blob/master/samples/vulkan_basics.md, and it said:

> OpenGL ES uses a synchronous rendering model, which means that an API call must behave as if all earlier API calls have already been processed. In reality no modern GPU works this way, rendering workloads are processed asynchronously and the synchronous model is an elaborate illusion maintained by the device driver. To maintain this illusion the driver must track which resources are read or written by each rendering operation in the queue, ensure that workloads run in a legal order to avoid rendering corruption, and ensure that API calls which need a data resource block and wait until that resource is safely available.
>
> Vulkan uses an asynchronous rendering model, reflecting how the modern GPUs work. Applications queue rendering commands into a queue, use explicit scheduling dependencies to control workload execution order, and use explicit synchronization primitives to align dependent CPU and GPU processing.
>
> The impact of these changes is to significantly reduce the CPU overhead of the graphics drivers, at the expense of requiring the application to handle dependency management and synchronization.

Could someone help explain why asynchronous rendering model could reduce CPU overhead? Since in Vulkan you still have to track state yourself.

Answer (score 4):

> Could someone help explain why asynchronous rendering model could
> reduce CPU overhead?

First of all, let's get back to the original statement you are referring to, emphasis mine:

> The impact of these changes is to significantly reduce the CPU
> overhead **of the graphics drivers**, [...]

So the claim here is that the driver itself will need to consume less CPU, and it is easy to see as it can more directly forward your requests "as-is".

However, one overall goal of a low-level rendering API like Vulkan is also a potentially reduced CPU overhead in general, not only in the driver.

Consider the following example: You have a draw call which renders to a texture. And then you have another draw call which samples from this texture.

To get the implicit synchronization right, the driver has to track the usage of this texture, both as render target and as source for texture sampling operations.

It doesn't know in advance if the next draw call will need any resources which are still to be written to in previous draw calls. It has to always track every possible such conflicts, no matter if they can occur in your application or not. And it also must be extremely conservative in its decisions. It might be possible that you have a texture bound for a framebuffer for a draw call, but you may know that with the actual uniform values you set for this shaders the texture is not modified. But the GPU driver can't know that. If it can't rule - out with absolute certainty - that a resource is modified, it has to assume it is.

However, your application will more like *know* such details. If you have several render passes, and the second pass will depend on the texture rendered to in the first, you can (and must) add proper synchronization primitives - but the GPU driver doesn't need to care *why* there is any synchronization necessary at all, and it doesn't need track any resource usage to find out - it can just do as it is told.  And your application also doesn't need to track it's own resource usage in many cases. It is just inherent from the usage as you coded it that a synchronization might be required at some point. There might be still cases where you need to track your own resource usage to find out though, especially if you write some intermediate layer like some more high-level graphics library where you know less and less of the structure of the rendering - then you are getting into a position similar to what a GL driver has to do (unless you want to forward all the burden of synchronization on the users of your library, like Vulkan does).